# Efficiently bulk-updating in ActiveRecord?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

How do I efficiently bulk-update records in ActiveRecord? I'm trying to populate a column which depends on another column.

This is my code now:

```
Tweet.find_in_batches do |group|
  to_be_saved = []
  group.each do |t|
    t.creation_date_posix = DateTime.strptime(t.creation_date_str, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M').to_time.to_i
    to_be_saved << t
  end
  Tweet.transaction do
    to_be_saved.each{|t| t.save}
  end
end
```

but it doesn't improve efficiency. Apparently `transaction` is not the right way to do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

In general, rather than spreading out bulk updates over `n` sql write statements, you can combine them all into one using [update_all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all). (Depending on a lot of variables) this can improve your overall performance.

Comment: How can I set a field as a function of another one with update_all ? Try to look at my code above, line 4. I'm setting a column (creation_date_posix) based on the value of another column (creation_date_str)

Comment: This will NOT call callbacks and hence might break things if you add a callback in the future